# Python: If-loop incomprehensible

Tags: python

I'm just modifying a small script for reading the serial-number and I'm struggling on getting the solution, why the script is behaving as it does. My target is, that I type in a serial number and it will be compared with the content in the list **config_parameters** - when the content is matching, it should print out test1 (just for testing purposes):

```
sn_input = input("Enter Serial Number :")
config_parameters = [
    {'hostname': 'switch-a', 'domain_name': 'domain.local', 'management_ip': '10.0.0.1', 'serial_number': '123'}, 
    {'hostname': 'switch-b', 'domain_name': 'domain.local', 'management_ip': '10.0.0.2', 'serial_number': '456'}, 
    {'hostname': 'switch-c', 'domain_name': 'domain.local', 'management_ip': '10.0.0.3', 'serial_number': '789'}, 
    {'hostname': 'switch-d', 'domain_name': 'domain.local', 'management_ip': '10.0.0.4', 'serial_number': '134'}
]


if sn_input in config_parameters:
    print('test1')
else:
    print('wrong')
```

As an additional hint: The {} in the list are from a dictionary, which content has been appended to the list (with the .append-function).

For example when I type in **123** as a serial number (that will be safed as **sn_input**), that is a part of an element in the list **config_parameters**, I will get the print wrong. That's where I'm stucking: Why does it go to the else-statement, although the **123** exists in that list? Even when I try to type in an complete entry, it well print out wrong. Why does it get to that and how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `config_parameters` is a list of dictionaries, not a list of strings.

Comment: How do you expect the input to match a whole dictionary? What are you really trying to match?

Comment: `123` does _not_ exist in the list, because it's a list of dictionaries (which are inherently not integers). You need to go one level deeper: `if sn_input in [item['serial_number'] for item in config_parameters]:` should do it, but this will be grossly inefficient because you're constructing the list on each call. You _could_ convert that list to a `set` but you're still constructing the list, then converting to a set, on each check. You need a separate data structure to store this.

Comment: I gave you the code for checking "part of the dictionary" but ideally you'll have another `set` that you `.add` to every time you encounter a new number. There's nothing wrong with your list of dictionaries as it is, but it's really inefficient when you want to come to check for membership, which I think is what you're doing frequently

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers and advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just test whether the input matches one of the `serial_number` items in the dictionaries, not the whole dictionary.

```
if any(c['serial_number'] == sn_input for c in config_parameters):
    print("test1")
else:
    print("wrong")
```